# HttpCookie to Cookie - how to deal with missing Domain?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cookies, httpwebrequest

I am creating a proxy page in ASP .NET (I need to get around cross-site scripting limitations). I need the `Page_Load` handler to send out an `HttpWebRequest` based on the incoming request to this page.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlToProxy);
request.Method = "GET";
request.GetResponse();
```

I'm running into some authentication problems (yes, I do set `request.Credentials` correctly, it's just not shown here), however, so I'd like to forward cookies from the incoming request (that hits my proxy page) to this outgoing request. You would think this would be straightforward:

```
request.CookieContiner = Request.Cookies;
```

However, this doesn't work. The outgoing `HttpWebRequest` uses `HttpCookie`s and the incoming `HttpRequest` uses `Cookie`s. These classes have no inheritance or interface relationship (indeed one is in `System.Net`, the other in `System.Web`.)

I've tried to copy the `HttpCookie`s into `Cookie`s and then add them to the `CookieContainer`, but I can't get this to work either.

```
 public static IEnumerable<Cookie> ToCookies(this HttpCookie cookie)
 {
    var cookies = new List<Cookie>(cookie.Values.Count);
    foreach (String key in cookie.Values)
    {
        cookies.Add(new Cookie()
        {
            Domain = cookie.Domain,
            Expires = cookie.Expires,
            HttpOnly = cookie.HttpOnly,
            Name = cookie.Name,
            Path = cookie.Path,
            Secure = cookie.Secure,
            Value = cookie.Values[key]
        });                
     }
     return cookies;
 }

 ...

 var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
 foreach(var httpCookie in Request.Cookies)
 {
     foreach(var cookie in httpCookie.ToCookies())
     {
         cookieContainer.Add(cookie); //Exception thrown here
     }
 }
```

The exception being thrown says that a `Cookie` cannot be added that has a `null` "Domain". Apparently, some of the `HttpCookie`s have `null` "Domain" properties.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way around this problem turning `HttpCookie` into `Cookie`? I'd like whatever solution I use with to be as general purpose as possible (and thus not involve hardcoding known domains into the new `Cookie`s.)

Even better, is there an easier way to do what I want simply using the `HttpRequest` class rather than the `HttpWebRequest` class?

Comment: What's the client on the other end? Is it a web site?

Comment: Yes. These are some additional characters to make this comment fulfill the character minimum on comments.

Comment: Are you sure a domain exists on the line Domain = cookie.Domain?

Comment: Also, what are the values that are set for one that fails?

Comment: No, nothing is set. `cookie.Domain` is null. Thus, the problem. How best to translate an `HttpCookie` to a `Cookie`.

Comment: So if none of the values are set, you're passing around an object that has been instantiated, but none of the properties have been set, it's not going to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: This isn't a C# language question. It's a "what's the most robust way to get around this framework issue" question. Obviously setting the "Domain" doesn't work, that's what the whole question is about. What's the best way to set it given the data in `Request.Cookies`.